# How to set SelectedItems property of GridView in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, gridview, selecteditem

I've got a gridview in my wpf application, the xaml of which looks like this:

```
   <ListView SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPartTypes}"
      local:DataGridService.SelectedItems="{Binding Path=SelectedPartTypes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                some columns...
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
```

Here is the attached behavior I'm using to get the selected items:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectedItems",
            typeof(IList),
            typeof(DataGridService),
             new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<object>() as IList, OnSelectedItemsChanged));

        static SelectionChangedEventHandler GetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (SelectionChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
        }
        static void SetSelectionChangedHandler(DependencyObject obj, SelectionChangedEventHandler value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, value);
        }
        static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionChangedHandler", typeof(SelectionChangedEventHandler),
            typeof(DataGridService), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        //d is MultiSelector (d as ListBox not supported)
        static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (GetSelectionChangedHandler(d) != null)
                return;

            if (d is MultiSelector)//DataGrid
            {
                MultiSelector multiselector = d as MultiSelector;
                SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;
                foreach (var selected in (d as DataGrid).SelectedItems) // GetSelectedItems(d) as IList)
                    multiselector.SelectedItems.Add(selected);

                selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    SetSelectedItems(d, multiselector.SelectedItems);
                };
                SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
                multiselector.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
            }
            else if (d is ListBox)
            {
                ListBox listbox = d as ListBox;
                SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionchanged = null;

                selectionchanged = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    SetSelectedItems(d, listbox.SelectedItems);
                };
                SetSelectionChangedHandler(d, selectionchanged);
                listbox.SelectionChanged += GetSelectionChangedHandler(d);
            }
        }

        public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject obj, IList value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }
```

This works fine for getting the selected items in the viewmodel when the user clicks a button or something.  My problem is that, when the screen loads, I need to highlight the items which were previously selected.  I unsuccessfully tried setting the 'SelectedPartTypes' property in the constructor of the VM, assuming that the two-way binding would take care of it.  Is there an easy way to show which items are selected when the control loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you bind the `IsSelected` property in the ListBoxItem Style?

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
</Style>
```

If your data objects don't have a property to track selection, you may need to use a converter to return true if the current object is within `SelectedPartTypes`

Comment: I tried this... I added an IsSelected property to my PartType object and set it to true for each selected object.  When the screen loads, nothing appears selected in the gridview, regardless of IsSelected being true or false.

Comment: @drowned Does it work without the `local:DataGridService.SelectedItems` binding?

Comment: Yes it works.  I can't believe I didn't run into this solution earlier when I found the crazy attached behavior option for dealing with multiple selected items.  Thank you.